# Can't find namespace even when having the 'using'?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I am using Unity and I'm getting a 'The type or namespace name 'Mine' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' error. I know this means that you are usually missing a using statement, but this is not the case this time. Take a look at the beginning of the 2 script at question. The error is flagged at "public WarmList list;"

```
using UnityEngine;
using Mine;

namespace PolymindGames.BuildingSystem
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(CookingStation))]
    //public class CampfireEffects : MonoBehaviour
    public sealed class CampfireEffects : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public WarmList list;
...
    }
}
```

And script 2

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Mine
{
     public class WarmList : MonoBehaviour
     {...
     }
}
```

Why can't script one see class 2? I don't think I am doing anything wrong? I have tried so many solutions but nothing works, I keep getting that complier error.

Comment: Does "Mine" show up under dependencies in your solution explorer in Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you maybe having an [Assembly definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) and forgot to [reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#reference-another-assembly) the other one as a dependency ..?

Comment: anjelomerte- It does not. I just made it up in the script because it wasn't seeing the class without a namespace. I thought adding would would make it easier for the first script to find my class.

Comment: derHugo - I don't really touch that and I'm embarrassed to say I don't know much about Assembly Definitions

Comment: This is Unity, right?  Are both scripts in your Assets folder?  Try letting the Unity Editor build the solution if you've been doing so in the IDE.